# Can someone check if I'm finding marginal pmf correctly?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So I was given this question and chart:

[image]

My first thought is using the equation from the book.
[image]

to get the answer
$$P_Y(x)=\begin{cases}1/6 & x = 0,1,2,3,4,5\\0 & otherwise\end{cases}$$

but I also learned in class that P_X(x) is just summing up everything in the column, so I'm thinking that the other answer might also be
$$P_X(0)=6/21, P_X(1)=5/21, P_X(2)=4/21, P_X(3)=3/21, P_X(4)=2/21, P_X(5)=1/21$$

So which way is the correct way of doing it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second is the correct way. You have $21$ outcomes which are equiprobable, hence you can compute the marginal using Laplace's equiprobability rule: $P(X) = \frac{favorable cases}{possible cases}$

Comment: Seems like you have made a typo; it should be $P_X(5)=1/21$

Comment: Thanks guys. was a big help

Answer (score 2):

You are not given that $Y$ is uniformly distributed so your first method does not work. It is $(X,Y)$ which is uniformly distributed over $21$ points of equal probability.

Indeed, the second method works and by symmetry, you can also conclude that $Y$ will be  distributed identically to $X$ i.e. will have the same PMF.